# Mutex guards: is there any automated protection mechanism for objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, posix

This scenario always occurs frequently: We have some threads, and a shared object, we need to make sure at any time only one thread can modify that object.

Well, the obvious solution is to use the `lock the door-do the job-get out of there` idiom. In this situation, I always use POSIX mutexes. For example

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&this->messageRW);     // lock the door
P_Message x = this->messageQueue.front(); // do the job
this->messageQueue.pop(); 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->messageRW);   // get out of there
// somewhere else, in another thread
while (true) {
    P_Message message;
    solver->listener->recvMessage(message);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(solver->messageRW));     // lock the door
    solver->messageQueue.push(message);           // do the job
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(solver->messageRW));   // get out of there
    sem_post(&solver->messageCount);
}
```

I use `messageQueue` in so many places in code. So ended up with a lot of lock/unlock pairs which are inelegant. I think there should be a way to declare `messageQueue` as an object that is supposed to be shared between threads, and then threading API can take care of lock/unlock. I can think of a wrapper class, or something similar. A POSIX-based solution is preferred though other API's (boost threads, or other libraries) are also acceptable.

What would you implement in a similar situation?

**Update for future readers**

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx). Will be a part of C++14 I guess.

Comment: Why not create a class containing a mutex and message queue, and expose public functions for accessing the queue and within those public functions the mutext is acquired and released. This removes the acquire/release from the client code.

Comment: Check e.g. [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: @hmjd Yes. That's the "wrapper class way" I mentioned in question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Documentation says `the lock is released when goes out of scope`. In the case that locking is needed in one scope, do `lock_guard` cause a deadlock?

Comment: Combine the method suggested by @hmjd, with the scoped lock guards, and you have a good solution.

Comment: It sounds like you want a concurrent queue. There are plenty of examples of that out there in the interwebs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg OK. So I'm going to implement a template class (parameter `T`) with overloaded `->` operator and a `std::mutex`. The `lock_guard` instance protects scope of `->()` operator. `->` itself return a `T&`. Is this safe?

Comment: I think it's not safe. Because when invoking something like `guarded_class_instance->critical_job()` scope of overloaded operator `->` ends before control reaches `critical_job()` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boost:scoped_lock` in this case. As soon as you go out of scope, it unlocks *elegantly*:

```
 boost::mutex mMutex;//member mutex object defined somewhere


{ //scope operator start
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock scopedLock(mMutex);
   pthread_mutex_lock();     // scoped lock the door
   P_Message x = this->messageQueue.front(); // do the job
   this->messageQueue.pop(); 
} //scope operator end, unlock mutex

// somewhere else, in another thread
while (true) {
    P_Message message;
    solver->listener->recvMessage(message);
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock scopedLock(mMutex);     // scoped lock the door
    solver->messageQueue.push(message);           // do the job
    sem_post(&solver->messageCount);
} //scope operator end, unlock mutex
```

Comment: What if scope is same? For example we need to access shared data in a scope, do some other staff, again check the data. Do we have deadlocks then?

Comment: @soroush, wherever you want to use scope_lock you can wrap with curly brackets{ } for scope control

Answer (score 2):

For this I would either subclass (is-a) or include (has-a) the message queue class into another class which forced the use of mutexes.

That's functionally what other languages do such as with the Java `synchronized` keyword - it modifieds the underlying object to be automatically protected.

Answer (score 1):

It's the message queue itself which should handle the locking
(be atomic), not the calling code.  And you need more than just
a mutex, you need a condition as well to avoid race conditions.
The standard idiom would be something like:

```
class ScopedLock    //  You should already have this one anyway
{
    pthread_mutex_t& myOwned;
    ScopedLock( ScopedLock const& );
    ScopedLock& operator=( ScopedLock const& );
public:
    ScopedLock( pthread_mutex_t& owned )
        : myOwned( owned )
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &myOwned );
    }
    ~ScopedLock()
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &myOwned );
    }
};

class MessageQueue
{
    std::deque<Message> myQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
    pthread_cond_t myCond;
public:
    MessageQueue()
    {
        pthread_mutex_init( &myMutex );
        pthread_cond_init( &myCond );
    }
    void push( Message const& message )
    {
        ScopedLock( myMutex );
        myQueue.push_back( message );
        pthread_cond_broadcast( &myCond );
    }

    Message pop()
    {
        ScopedLock( myMutex );
        while ( myQueue.empty() ) {
            pthread_cond_wait( &myCond, &myMutex );
        }
        Message results = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.pop_front();
        return results;
    }
};
```

This needs more error handling, but the basic structure is
there.

Of course, if you can use C++11, you'ld be better off using the
standard thread primitives.  (Otherwise, I'd normally suggest
Boost threads.  But if you're already using Posix threads, you
might want to wait to convert until you can use standard
threads, rather than converting twice.)  But you'll still need
both a mutex and a condition.

Comment: @MartinJames That's doing things the hard way (and he didn't post the code where he synchronizes on it in the read).

Comment: Yes, but there seems little point in the sem_post unless the read is doing a sem_wait.

Comment: @MartinJames Agreed.  It was, in fact, looking at the read, and the absence of any synchronization, that led to my answer.